# Consistency in a Login Model using the Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get my head around a login model that uses several authentication methods.

1.) For example, when a new user tries to log in with OpenID my backend is going to insert two entities into the datastore:

- Insert a new user, where the automatically inserted id will be his $userId

  `(kind: User, id: autoId)`
- Insert a new login that is linked to the $userId

  `(kind: AuthOpenid, name: $openId), Property(userId: $userId)`

This will allow me to make lookup by key requests when a user tries to log in, which enforces strongly consistent data, right?

The idea is that one user can have many logins (like stackexchange) and I don't have to worry about write/read limits because no entities have ancestors while still enforcing consistency.

2.) On a related note: Assuming my users are allowed to pick a username once they have provided an authentication method, how do I efficiently check if a username is taken?

My idea was to insert a new entity for every picked username.

- Insert a new username

  `(kind: Username, name: $username)`

Now I can simply make a lookup by key request to see if a username is taken. As far as I know, common lookups will be stored in memcache anyways, so this should be efficient, right?

I could also reverse the procedure and just attempt to insert a username and see if it fails.

Comment: if you are using NDB you'll get the automatic caching in some cases, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Your approach looks good. As you've noted, `Lookup` operations (lookup by key) are [guaranteed to return consistent results](https://developers.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview#Datastore_Datastore_writes_and_data_visibility).

You're also correct that by putting each AuthOpenid entity in its own entity group (no common ancestor), you will avoid the write throughput limit of [1 write/second](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) on any particular entity group (there's no corresponding limit on rate of entity group creation).

2) This will also work, but you will need to execute the read and write operations as part of a transaction. This ensures that if two users try to reserve the same username, only one of them will succeed.

In Cloud Datastore, an `insert` mutation will fail if an entity with the same key already exists, so this will also work.

(Note that this is different from the `put()` operation in the App Engine Datastore which uses upsert semantics.)

Comment: 1.) Isn't the 1 write per second limit irrelevant in this case? Let's say I have a spike in sign ups with 10 people trying to sign up simultaneously. As you've stated, each authentication entity will be its own entity group. They might have the same key (i.e. AuthOpenId, AuthFacebook) but that doesn't affect the limit, right?

Comment: 2.) I'm using PHP and commit insert attempts do raise an error if the entity already exsists.

Comment: 3.) Do you by any chance know if it'll be possible to migrate a cloud datastore into the native PHP datastore once it becomes available?

Comment: 1) Yes, that's exactly right. I've edited my answer to a little clearer.

2 + 3) Are you using the Google APIs Client Library (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the library but I'm creating the JSON requests myself without the use of Google_DatastoreService.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The insert mutation in Cloud Datastore has the behavior you're describing (I thought you were using a put() operation in App Engine Datastore). Updated my answer again.